# Проверить расширение загружаемых файлов

Tags: php

```
$files = array_keys($_FILES['work_img']['name']);
 foreach($files as $k) {
                if($_FILES['work_img']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg") $fileend = '.jpg';
                elseif($_FILES['work_img']['type'][$k] == "image/png") $fileend = '.png';
                elseif($_FILES['work_img']['type'][$k] == "image/gif") $fileend = '.gif';
                else {
                    $error .= 'Изображения могут быть в формате JPG, PNG или GIF';
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Я гружу несколько файлов через форму. Файлы грузятся прекрасно и все отлично работает, кроме данного куска кода. Я не могу понять, почему мне все время $error возвращает, даже когда я картинки гружу. Хотя от части уверен, что это из за foreach. Че то я там не того наделал. Помогите исправить плиз

Answer (score 1):

Что содержит данный кусок кода: `$_FILES['work_img']['type'][$k]`? Вероятно - ничего, т.к. вы неправильно разбираете массив.

```
foreach($_FILES['work_img'] as $ArrV) {
    if($ArrV['type'] == "image/jpeg") {
        $fileend = '.jpg';
    }
    elseif($ArrV['type'] == "image/png") {
        $fileend = '.png';
    }
    elseif($ArrV['type'] == "image/gif") {
        $fileend = '.gif';
    }
    else {
        $error .= 'Изображения могут быть в формате JPG, PNG или GIF';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: та же проблема. Все равно выводит ошибку в любом случае

Comment: @inferus-vv что выдает var_dump($_FILES['work_img']) ? залейте сюда: http://pastebin.com

Comment: Вот-вот. Это кажется странным, но именно этот разбор будет неправильным, потому что,например статус i-того файла будет в  `$_FILE['blabla']['error'][i]`, а не в `$_FILE['blabal'][i]['error']`

Comment: Спасибо, ребята. Сам разобрался :)

Answer (score 1):

Это не правильная проверка изображения на изображение! Используйте [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php).

[**Безопасная загрузка изображений на сервер**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44610/)

Comment: А чем по MIME не подходит?

Comment: очень легко подделать

Answer (score 0):

`$error .= 'Изображения могут быть в формате JPG, PNG или GIF, получено значение: '.$_FILES['work_img']['type'][$k];`

Видимо $_FILES['work_img']['type'][$k] просто пустое, поэтому всё сваливается в ошибку.